Fast step-response, low cutoff frequency digital LPF
I've designed a digital butterworth low pass filter to remove some structure vibration noise (with components arround 2.5Hz) in a weight reading system. In a first approach I've used a first order, 0.1Hz cutoff frequency filter, but the filter step response was too slow, in a way that when inserting a weight on the system, it took arround 5 seconds for the reading to stabilize, even though when using a moving average filter, the readings take less 0.5 seconds to stabilize. Later on, I tried using a third order, 1Hz cutoff frequency, but had the same problem.
Is this an issue with butterworth filters? Is there a way to get a faster response?
I've used python to get the coefficients and then implemented the code on C language. For the python scipt, I've used the function [b, a] = scipy.signal.butter(1, 1, 'low', False, 'ba', 40) to get the coefficients, which resulted in b = [0.07295966 0.07295966], a = [ 1.         -0.85408069] for the first order filter and b = [0.00041655 0.00124964 0.00124964 0.00041655], a = [ 1.         -2.6861574   2.41965511 -0.73016535] for the third order filter.
As for the C implementation, I've used the function
int32_t butter(int32_t * in, int32_t * out, uint8_t order)
{
    double filt = 0;
    const double a[4] = {1, -2.6861574, 2.41965511, -0.73016535};
    const double b[4] = {0.00041655, 0.00124964, 0.00124964, 0.00041655};
    

    for(int i = 0; i<= order;i++) filt += b[i] * in[i];
    for(int i = 1; i<= order;i++) filt -= a[i] * out[i];

    return (int32_t)filt;
}

The C function seems to work, as I've got the same results as the scipy.signal.lfilter() function in python, using a 40Hz sampling frequency all arround.

Welcome to our SE. Unfortunately you have run into a fundamental problem often referred to as the Fourier uncertainty. Roughly speaking: your frequency resolution is inversely proportional to your time resolution. So if there is a steep gradient at or before 2.5Hz, the impulse (or step) response will be at least 4 seconds long .

@Hilmar: really, that's an answer right there, even if it's short.

Fundamentally, the sharper of an edge that you have in the frequency response of a linear filter, the longer it'll take to settle out in the time domain$^1$.
Of necessity, a low-pass filter needs some minimum sharpness to its transition from passband to stopband -- so the lower the frequency that a low-pass passes, the longer it'll take to settle out.
This applies to high-pass filters, bandpass filters, and bandstop filters as well -- it's just a bit less intuitive.

(1) This is the "Fourier uncertainty" that Hilmar mentions in his comment.

If you're always changing weight by a significant amount -- i.e., adding or subtracting mostly-known chunks of weight -- you could sense this and restart your weight acquisition.  Your filter would be nonlinear and harder to design and verify, and would have a much greater tendency to be squirrely in the field.  If the vibration is at a known frequency you could notch it out -- this also has complications, but may work well.  If you're interested in either of these approaches ask a new question and be sure to add enough detail for us to help, or be ready to edit your question when we ask.
